# Tic tac toe game: how do I add the value to the array when I click the square

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a tic tac toe in javascript and i'm stuck at this problem. There's not a lot of code in my js file so here it is:

I have this function that makes my squares (bunch of divs in a container) have the same values that are stored in the array

```
    const containercube = document.querySelector('.container');
    const quadrados = containercube.children;

    var gameboard= ["","","","x","","","","",""];

    const update = () =>{
    
    
        for (let i = 0; i < gameboard.length; i += 1) {

            quadrados[i].innerHTML= gameboard[i];
    
     }
    }
```

So far so good, this is the part that works.

Now this is where I'm having trouble, I tried making a function that will add an "X" to the array position that corresponds to the square's index but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
      const placeToken = (target, token) => {
    gameboard[target] = token;
    update();
  };

  

containercube.addEventListener('click', function clickEvent(quadrados) {
        const tokenze = "x";
        placeToken(quadrados.target.dataset.index, tokenze);
        update();
    
})
```

Comment: "_There's not a lot of code in my js_". so why not share a working example as snippet (hit `Ctrl  + M` in your question editor)

Comment: Please also share the html

Comment: Hello @Gabriel, Few months ago i've developed tic-tac-toe gate in react application, please go through it might be help you to develop logic in your own way. https://github.com/ankitkanojia/tic-tac-toe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a better way to do this.
But here is a working code with minimum edits

```
const containercube = document.querySelector('.container');
    const quadrados = containercube.children;
    let gameboard= ["","","","x","","","","",""];
    const update = () =>{
        for (let i = 0; i < gameboard.length; i += 1) {
            quadrados[i].innerHTML= gameboard[i];
     }
    }
    update();
    
const placeToken = (target, token) => {
    gameboard[target] = token;
    update();
  };
  
//Edited part  
for (let i = 0; i < gameboard.length; i += 1) { 
    const tokenze = "x";
    quadrados[i].addEventListener('click',()=>{
        placeToken(i, tokenze);
        //removed the update
    });
}
```